# Variable nula en laravel 10 cuando se intenta subir una imagen

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de subir una imagen en conjunto con un texto en laravel 10. Pero el problema con el codigo del store. Basicamente devuelve un error que dice que la funcion extension es nula. Y honestamente no entiendo el por que.

```
$fileName = time(). '.' . $request->file->extension();
$request->file->move(public_path('images'), $fileName); 

$info= new Info;
$info->name = $request->name;
$info->file_uri = $fileName;
$info->save();
```

Espero que me puedan dar una mano. Estoy aprendiendo a usar laravel 10 y honestamente esto de subir imágenes no me resulta.

Comment: te consta que tu input se llama "file"  y no "imagen" o algún otro nombre? Si estás siguiendo un tutorial no asumas que "$request->file"  hay que tomarlo literal

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que tu campo se llame de otra manera (distinto a file), si no especificas el nombre del campo, entonces este tomará por default `file` cuando tratas de recuperar la extensión del archivo `$request->file->extension()`.

Trata de hacerlo así: `$request->file('nombreDelCampo')->extension();`

Espero que te sirva.